# Accidentally cloned the same git repository inside my git respository

Tags: git

I have my git repository on my local machine and I accidentally cloned the same git repository inside it. For eg, my git repository contains the directory structure /A/B/ and inside /A/B I cloned the same repository so now I have /A/B/A/B/. Obviously now I'm unable to track anything correctly in the old repository now. Is there a way to undo the clone without deleting the entire old repository and re creating it?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Delete the nested clone /a/b/a/b and do your work in a/b/

Answer (score 1):

Just delete the new repository:

```
$ cd /A/B
$ rm -rf A
```

that should do it.